Passing an array as a parameter from PowerShell to an SQL script
I'm creating a quite complex SQL script to delete from a database a bunch of records. Because I have to do a lot of operations, I want to save the IDs of the records I have to delete in a temporary table
DECLARE @RunIDsToDelete TABLE (RunID INT);

INSERT INTO @RunIDsToDelete (RunID)
VALUES
       N'$(runIDs)'

The list of IDs to delete - alias to save in the table - must to be a parameter from the PowerShell script. The SQL script has to send back to the PowerShell script the confirmation that I want to read.
$runIds = @(1, 2)
$paramList = $runIds -join ","

$sqlCommand = "sqlcmd -S sql1 -d mydb -i $($sqlScriptPath) -v IDs=$paramList"

My first attempt was to prepare the list and pass the result string to the SQL script but I get this error

sqlcmd : Sqlcmd: ',(2),(4)': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: ',(2),(... '-?' for help.:String) [], 
                          RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Then, I tried to pass a string like that
$sqlCommand = "sqlcmd -S sql1 -d myDb -i $($sqlScriptPath) -v IDs=""(1), (2)"""

but again I get the same error. How can I pass the list of IDs then?

What you need here is a table type ("structured") parameter. If you use modules like DbaTools, and it's Invoke-DbaQuery command, then you'll likely have an easier time implementing it.

For this purpose, you may be better off using the ADO.Net objects over the sqlcmd program, which have good support for table-value parameters.

You need to just use escape character inside to handle that string. Escape is backtic(`) in PS. Before the button 1.

As I mention in the comments, this is much easier with something like the DbaTools module. Then you can use New-DbaSqlParameter to create add a table type parameter, built by using ConvertTo-DbaDataTable, and pass it to Invoke-DbaQuery.
Take the following overly simplified table:
CREATE TABLE dbo.StructuredTest (ID int IDENTITY,
                                 SomeString varchar(10),
                                 SomeInt int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.StructuredTest (SomeString,
                                SomeInt)
VALUES('abc',1),
      ('def',2),
      ('xyz',1);

Now we want to pass a list of IDs (ints). We would need a table type, such as:
CREATE TYPE dbo.Ints AS table(IntValue int);

Then we can use the following script from PowerShell to pass a table type as the type dbo.Ints:
#Define the initial query
$Query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.StructuredTest ST WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableVariable TV WHERE TV.Intvalue = ST.ID);'

#Define an Array
$IDs = @()
#Add the rows to the array. According to the documentation, these should be PSCustomObjects
$IDs += [PSCustomObject]@{Intvalue = 1}
$IDs += [PSCustomObject]@{Intvalue = 2}
#Convert to a DataTable
$DT = ConvertTo-DbaDataTable -InputObject $IDs

#Create the parameter. TypeName is the TYPE in your database. TableVariable the name of the variable/parameter in your query (without the @)
$TableVariable = New-DbaSqlParameter -ParameterName TableVariable -SqlDbType Structured -Value $DT -TypeName 'dbo.Ints'

#Run the query, passing your (Table) Variable)
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance 'SandboxServer' -Database Sandbox -Query $Query -SqlParameter $TableVariable

If you wanted to do an INSERT against the table, then it would look something like this:
--Create TYPE in SQL Server
CREATE TYPE dbo.StructuredType AS table (SomeString varchar(10),
                                         SomeInt int);

#PoSh Script to INSERT data into SQL Server:
$Query = 'INSERT INTO dbo.StructuredTest (SomeString, SomeInt) SELECT SomeString, SomeInt FROM @TableVariable;'

$Rows = @()
$Rows += [PSCustomObject]@{SomeString = 'ghi'
                           SomeInt = 2}
$Rows += [PSCustomObject]@{SomeString = 'ace'
                           SomeInt = 3}
$DT = ConvertTo-DbaDataTable -InputObject $Rows
$TableVariable = New-DbaSqlParameter -ParameterName TableVariable -SqlDbType Structured -Value $DT -TypeName 'dbo.StructuredType'

Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance 'SandboxServer' -Database Sandbox -Query $Query -SqlParameter $TableVariable




sqlcmd.exe has its own, nonstandard double-quoting requirements with respect to -v arguments, which run afoul of how PowerShell builds the process command line for external-program calls behind the scenes.

In short, sqlcmd.exe needs to see a -v argument with selective double-quoting, namely around the value part only, e.g. FOO="bar" and FOO="bar baz", whereas PowerShell turns these arguments into FOO=bar and "FOO=bar baz" behind the scenes.

See GitHub issue #18554 for an extensive discussion.



As a workaround, you can use PowerShell's broken passing of arguments with embedded " characters (double quotes) to external programs. That is, you can use embedded " here and rely on their not getting escaped as \" behind the scenes.

While the broken behavior is fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.3+ , where getting the old, broken behavior back now requires opt-in via $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy', this opt-in isn't actually necessary for sqlcmd.exe, because it is on an exception list of known executables to which the old behavior continues to be applied automatically in the default $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing mode, 'Windows' - see the docs for the complete list.



The following shows the solution as a direct invocation of your sqlcmd.exe command rather than creating a string representation of it:
$runIds = @(1, 2)
$paramList = $runIds.ForEach({ '(' + $_ + ')' }) -join ',' # -> "(1),(2)"

# Note the embedded, escaped " chars. around $paramList
sqlcmd -S sql1 -d mydb -i $sqlScriptPath -v IDs=`"$paramList`"

To get the command as a string representation, using an expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string ("..."), as in your own attempt, both the embedded " and ` themselves requires `-escaping:
$sqlCommand =
  "sqlcmd -S sql1 -d mydb -i `"$sqlScriptPath`" -v IDs=```"$paramList```""

However, note that there's usually no reason to store a full command line in a string (typically for ill-advised use with Invoke-Expression), because PowerShell makes it easy to construct command lines programmatically that can be invoked directly - see this answer for more information, and this answer for how to pass arguments stored in an array.

I fundamentally agree with this answer - using DbaTools would make your life easier - but here's how you could do it programmatically from PowerShell without invoking any external tools:
$runIDs = @(1, 2, 3)

# establish connection
$connection = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::new("connection string goes here")
$connection.Open()

# define the first part of the command text
$cmdTextPreamble = @'
DECLARE @RunIDsToDelete TABLE (RunID INT);

INSERT INTO @RunIDsToDelete (RunID) 
VALUES 
'@

# create a command object
$cmd = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]::new()
$cmd.Connection = $connection

# now construct the final command text, one insertion at a time
$cmdText = $cmdTextPreamble
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $runIDs.Count; $i++) {
  # calculate the next parameter name
  $paramName = "@runID${i}"
  # add the parameterized value set to the command text
  $cmdText += "(${paramName}),"
  # and bind the corresponding value to the parameter name
  $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($paramName, $runIDs[$i]) |Out-Null
}

# remove trailing `,` from the command text and update the $cmd object
$cmd.CommandText = $cmdText.TrimEnd(',')

# execute insert command
$rowCount = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Write-Host "Inserted ${rowCount} rows into table"

